# Chartjs - my old data show sometimes, bugs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have problem is kinda weird, well i have filter, if i picked filter date and ftycode on first time, is show my data on chart. But when i change my filter, is kinda bug, well is reloading or update my data on chart but when i'm hover the chart sometimes my old data chart still show. 
This my coding

```
var data = {
    labels: countline,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'QTY Target',
            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.8)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.75)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            data: countqtytarget
        },
        {
            label: 'Qty Sewing',
            fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.8)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.75)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
            data: countsew
        },
        {
            label: 'Qty QC Output',
            fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
            data: countqc
        },
        {
            label: 'Qty Right First Time (RFT)',
            fillColor: 'rgba(57,10,150,0.2)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(76,34,160,1)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(76,34,160,1)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(76,34,160,1)',
            data: countrft
        },
        {
            label: 'Qty Repair (RPR)',
            fillColor: 'rgba(227,255,0,0.2)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            data: countrpr
        },
        {
            label: 'Qty Polly Bag',
            fillColor: 'rgba(71,180,2,0.2)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            highlightFill: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            highlightStroke: 'rgba(241,255,127,1)',
            data: countpolly
        }]
};

// Chart.js Options
var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,

    // Sets the chart to be responsive
    responsive: true,

    //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,

    //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines: true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,

    //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
    barShowStroke: true,

    //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
    barStrokeWidth: 2,

    //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
    barValueSpacing: 5,

    //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
    barDatasetSpacing: 1,

    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate: '<ul class="tc-chart-js-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
};
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
$('#rchart2')
    .empty(); // this is my <canvas> element
$('#canvas')
    .append('<canvas id="chart2" class="full-width"></canvas>');
var ctx = $("#chart2")
    .get(0)
    .getContext("2d");
// This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var chart2 = new Chart(ctx)
    .Bar(data, options);
//generate the legend
var legend = chart2.generateLegend();
//and append it to your page somewhere
$('#chart1Legend')
    .empty();
$('#chart2Legend')
    .append(legend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the `<canvas>` element and then reappending a new `<canvas>` element to the parent container?

This is something I use. This is the only way to get rid of the hover events and such.

```
var resetCanvas = function(){
  $('#results-graph').remove(); // this is my <canvas> element
  $('#graph-container').append('<canvas id="results-graph"><canvas>');
  canvas = document.querySelector('#results-graph');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = $('#graph').width(); // resize to parent width
  ctx.canvas.height = $('#graph').height(); // resize to parent height
  var x = canvas.width/2;
  var y = canvas.height/2;
  ctx.font = '10pt Verdana';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText('This text is centered on the canvas', x, y);
};
```